# How to delete a selected number of rows from CoreData using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to delete a selected list of items from a CoreData table: A number of Persons with certain `namesToDelete`:

```
NSError*        error        = nil;
NSFetchRequest* request      = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                               inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate*    predicate    = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (name IN %@)", namesToDelete];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray*         deleteArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error == nil)
{
    for (NSManagedObject* object in deleteArray)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
    }

    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    //### Error handling.
}
else
{
    //### Error handling.
}
```

This works, but is this the easiest/shortest way to do this in CoreData?

Comment: You can reduce a couple of lines but that is the process.

Comment: @Wain Please tell me how in an answer and I will reward you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to iOS 9 we delete the object one by one but on iOS 9.0+ we can delete them in a batch.

You can use [`NSBatchDeleteRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html) available on `iOS 9.0+`, `macOS 10.11+`, `tvOS 9.0+`, `watchOS 2.0+`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (name IN %@)", namesToDelete]];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Person fetchRequest];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
// Create batch delete request
NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteReq = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
deleteReq.resultType = NSBatchDeleteResultTypeCount;
NSError *error = nil;
NSBatchDeleteResult *deletedResult = [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:deleteReq error:&error];
if (error) {
  NSLog(@"Unable to delete the data");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"%@ deleted", deleteReq.result);
}
```

---

Swift code (from the above link)

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Employee")
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "terminationDate < %@", NSDate())
let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetch)

do {
    let result = try moc.execute(request)
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to execute request: \(error)")
}
```

---

#### NOTE:

I found below comment about `execute` of `moc`

> Method to pass a request to the store without affecting the contents of the managed object context.

Which means any unsaved data in `moc` won't be affected. i.e. if you've created/updated entity that falls in the delete request criteria and don't called `save` on `moc` then that object won't be deleted.

Comment: As iOS 9+ is the standard now (for most), this should become the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @meaning-matters added swift code for swift users :)

Answer (score 6):

About the best trimming is something like:

```
NSError*        error        = nil;
NSFetchRequest* request      = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (name IN %@)", namesToDelete]];
NSArray*         deleteArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (deleteArray != nil)
{
    for (NSManagedObject* object in deleteArray)
    {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];
    }

    [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    //### Error handling.
}
else
{
    //### Error handling.
}
```

Note also that you check if the array is returned as the success criteria, not tat the error in `nil`. Likewise for the `save:` you should check the returned `BOOL`.

Comment: Thanks man, and for the amazingly fast reply!  Unfortunately CoreData does not seem to be good in one-liners.

Comment: If you were going to do this a lot you can write a utility method that takes the entity name and predicate and returns a BOOL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's it.  There is no SQL-like delete capability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So there is no line(s) to save for deleting my "NOT (name IN %@)" excluded list?  I don't need to use a predicate, just want to know the shortest code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i use in Swift.

```
func deleteRecentWithId(recentID : String)
{
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Recent_Message> = Recent_Message.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recentUserOrGroupid = %@", recentID)
    let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)

    do {
        try context.execute(request)
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print ("There was an error")
    }

}
```

Just change your table name and predicate condition. **Enjoy!!!**

Comment: Glad to know that it helps you !!